# ComboBox in javaFX

Tags: java, combobox, javafx, scenebuilder

I have some problem with comboBox in javaFX. I design my combobox in scene builder:

```
<ComboBox fx:id="categoryComboBox" prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="405.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2">
      <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
          <String fx:value="Woodenware" />
          <String fx:value="Stoneware" />
          <String fx:value="Metalware" />
          <String fx:value="Fabric" />
        </FXCollections>
      </items>
    </ComboBox>
```

This is my controller class:

```
 @FXML
private ComboBox<?> categoryComboBox;
public void setCategoryComboBox(ComboBox<String> categoryComboBox) {
    this.categoryComboBox = categoryComboBox;
}

public ComboBox<String> getCategoryComboBox() {
    return categoryComboBox;
}

@FXML
private void comboBoxSelection(ActionEvent event) {
   categoryComboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
         public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, 
             String old_val, String new_val) {
                String categoryStr =  getCategoryComboBox().getValue().toString(); //Don't know what to put here
     }
```

When I try to get selected item from comboBox:

```
  int category = panel.getCategoryComboBox().getValue()
```

It gives me an error message "incompatible data tyep and I have no idea why. I am new to scene builder and netbeans so please tell me where am I did wrongly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/3062859, for your reference.

Comment: Please accept the answer that works for you @OmarAlhadidy https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 0):

Your ComboBox has a  generic type specifier on it, so any value it returns will be a String.

You cannot assign a String to an int, which is why you get an "incompatible data type" error which you try to do so.

If instead, you set the category type to a String, you will no longer get an "incompatible data type error"

```
String category = panel.getCategoryComboBox().getValue()
```

Comment: Ok thanks alot. I've solved it but I not sure whether am I doing it in the correct way or not.

Comment: you there? I have some problem on comboBox

Comment: @Carol I am not sure what your current problem is.  I think that if you follow the instructions in my answer and look to the gist sample which Shreyas posted in a comment then you will be able to fix your original type incompatibility problem (hint: replace all <?> with <String>).  If you still have issues, construct and post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and full error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line:

```
private ComboBox<?> categoryComboBox;
```

You can't cast from `?` to `int`. So change this line to:

```
private ComboBox<Integer> categoryComboBox;
```

Then you have to change the methode:

```
public ComboBox<String> getCategoryComboBox() {...}
```

to

```
 public ComboBox<Integer> getCategoryComboBox() {...}
```